# Travelling at or near the speed of light towards a distant galaxy, looking ahead, would you actually see it moving?

Tags: ftl

Its known that when you look up at the night sky at distant galaxies you are not seeing what they look like today, due to light speed being the ultimate speed limit, the light you see was actually emitted a very long time ago. So with that in mind:

If you were in a spaceship moving at light speed or very near to it, and you were traveling towards a distant galaxy.   If you looked forward, would the galaxy appear to rotate faster as you closed the gap?

Comment: When moving towards a galaxy **AT** the speed of light, you would not see it. Or anything. Because your very existence will have destroyed the whole universe.

Answer (score 2):

The view out the front window as you accelerate towards the speed of light is totally different than the Star Trek version.

There is angular compression, so distant objects cluster closer together, rather than zip back over your shoulders. As the objects move towards the “vanishing point”, they rotate so you are looking at their back side rather than their front side. All light is blue shifted and gets brighter. Your whole view shrinks into a blinding spot of ultraviolet rays. Then you die.

And that’s just warp 0.8

Comment: Gamma rays or merely ultraviolet at warp "only" 0.8? Not that it would make much of a difference to bliding or survivability.

Comment: You’re right. No Gamma at Warp 0.8. Isaac Newton certainly would only get UV. Albert Einstein may see more shift due to time dilation?

Comment: In fact the blue shift is less with Einstein due to time dilation. I calculate a factor of 3 at W0.8, which still gets you far enough into UV to do damage (otherwise visible photons raised to between 4 and 9 eV).

Comment: You're right. Can you provide a reference? I was (obviously) unsuccessful with the physics.

Comment: Look at the first box [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/reldop2.html). Note that wavelength is inversely proportional to frequency.

Comment: If Newton looks out the front window at warp 0.8 and counts wavefronts (N), as they arrive for a second, he will see a frequency of N Hz. If Einstein does the same, time will have dilated by about 70% and he will count 70% more wavelengths when his stopwatch passes the second mark. Doesn’t that mean he sees the radiation at higher frequency? But how does Einstein measure the wavelength when his Lorentz-Fitzgerald ruler has contracted?

Comment: The formulae, however, do give frequency and thus observed photon energy.

Comment: Thanks for walking me through that.